# Extract only numbers from link with codeception

Tags: php, regex, codeception

I have this link, and i need to work only with the numbers from that link.
How would i extract them?

I didn't find any answer that would work with codepcetion.

https://www.my-website.com/de/booking/extras#tab-nav-extras-1426

I tired something like this.

```
 $I->grabFromCurrentUrl('\d+');
```

But i won't work.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried with these alternative methods? `[\d]+` or `[0-9]+`

Comment: If the number will always at the end of the URL, you could also add the "end-of-string" operator: `[0-9]+$`

Comment: Yes @GergelyLukacsy this is the kind of error message i get "   [PHPUnit_Framework_Exception] preg_match(): Unknown modifier '+' "

Comment: I think I found the problem, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Staying within the framework:

The [manual](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver#grabFromCurrentUrl) clearly says that:

> grabFromCurrentUrl
>
> Executes the given regular expression against the current URI and
>   returns the **first capturing group**. If no parameters are provided, the
>   full URI is returned.

Since you didn't used any capturing groups `(...)`, nothing is returned.

Try this:

```
    $I->grabFromCurrentUrl('~(\d+)$~');
```

The `$` at the end is optional, it just states that the string should end with the pattern.

Also note that the opening and closing pattern delimiters you would normally use (`/`) are replaced by tilde (`~`) characters for convenience, since the input string has a great chance to contain multiple forward slashes. Custom [pattern delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) are completely standard in regexp, as @Naktibalda pointed it out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51743165/1957951).

Comment: I tried without the $ sign, and i think we are getting somewhat closer. Fail message below.

Comment: Step  Grab from current url "(\d+)"
 Fail  Nothing to grab. A regex parameter required. Ex: '/user/(\d+)'

Comment: Maybe it needs the `~` signs like this: `$I->grabFromCurrentUrl('~(\d+)~');`
Looks like Codeception's regexp deters from the standard syntax.

Comment: Exactly what i needed *Claps slowly*. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. I modify the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php) to parse entire URL and then extract the part which is most interested for you. After that you can use regex to extract only numbers from the string.

```
$url = "https://www.my-website.com/de/booking/extras#tab-nav-extras-1426";
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);

$fragment = $parsedUrl['fragment']; // Contains: tab-nav-extras-1426

$id = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $fragment);

var_dump($id); // Output: string(4) "1426"
```

Comment: Wow this actually worked.  You just saved me a lot of time. Could you maybe explain how this works ? I don't really get $parsedUrl['fragment'] this part.

Comment: @MewTwo you're welcome! If it worked feel free to mark my response as correct one :)

Comment: Also would there be any way ? To make the link dynamic. Since the numbers may change every test. Thats why i tried using the function from codepcetion. If no this will also work fine.

Comment: @MewTwo take a look on documentation of parse_url() it returns you an array with aggregated parts of the url. In your case part which you need is in "fragment" part.

Comment: @MewTwo with php you can get full url like this, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

Answer (score 0):

A variant using [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) after [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$url = "https://www.my-website.com/de/booking/extras#tab-nav-extras-1426";

preg_match('/\d+$/', parse_url($url)['fragment'], $id);

var_dump($id[0]);
// Outputs: string(4) "1426"
```