# Codeception URL regex

Tags: php, regex, codeception

So the official documentation says absolutely nothing about the tilde sign (`~`) used in regexp patterns, for example as in the `seeCurrentUrlMatches()` function. Yet, it is used extensively in the documentation.

In the exmample, the regexp looks like this:

```
    $I->seeCurrentUrlMatches('~$/users/(\d+)~');
```

- Without the tilde sign, it gives an error. eg. `grabFromCurrentUrl('(\d+)')` returns:

  > " (\d+)" Fail Nothing to grab. A regex parameter required.
- The end-of-string regexp operator's (`$`)
  position makes no sense (I presume the dollar sign has a completely
  different meaning in this context */my guess would be shorthand for the home path/*.)
- In standard regexp, the `~` captures the character itself

My conclusion is the regexp pattern that Codeception expects from you is clearly non-standard. So what does the `~` and `$` do? Where can I find a throughout documentation or article about this?

Comment: My guess is, that just like `preg_match()`, the pattern needs to be encapuslated by a special sign, which can be chosen the user and was chosen as a tilde by the author of the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Codeception doesn't use any special regex functions.

`seeCurrentUrlMatches` method calls PhpUnit's `assertRegexp` method which uses `preg_match` under the hood.

`preg_match` uses pattern [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric character.
`/` is the most common delimiter, but it is inconvenient for matching URL, because you would have to escape a lot of slashes in URL, so using `~` as a delimiter avoids need to escape.

`$` at the beginning of pattern is probably a simple mistake in example.

Comment: Thank you, I think it's makes sense now.